# Docker Mysql container: Connection Refused

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

So I have the following `docker-compose.yml` and `.env` file.

```yaml
version: "3"
services:

  cx_cache:
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}_cache
    image: redis:7.2.2-alpine
    networks:
      - ${APP_NAME}_directus


  cx_mysql:
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}_mysql
    image: mysql:8.2
    command: mysqld --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 3306
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: ${MYSQL_ROOT_HOST}
      MYSQL_HOST: ${MYSQL_HOST}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${APP_NAME}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_TCP_PORT: 3306

  directus:
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}_directus
    build:
      dockerfile: "Dockerfile"
    ports:
      - 8055:8055
    volumes:
      - ./uploads:/directus/uploads
      - ./extensions:/directus/extensions
    networks:
      - ${APP_NAME}_directus
    depends_on:
      - ${APP_NAME}_cache
      - ${APP_NAME}_mysql
    environment:
      HOST: 0.0.0.0
      PORT: 8055
      KEY: "${APP_KEY}"
      SECRET: "${APP_SECRET}"
      DB_CLIENT: "mysql"
      DB_HOST: "localhost"
      DB_PORT: "3306"
      DB_DATABASE: "${APP_NAME}"
      DB_USER: "${MYSQL_USER}"
      DB_PASSWORD: "${MYSQL_PASSWORD}"
      DB_EXCLUDE_TABLES: "spatial_ref_sys,sysdiagrams"
      
      CACHE_ENABLED: "true"
      CACHE_STORE: "redis"
      CACHE_REDIS: "redis://${APP_NAME}_cache:6379"
      
      ADMIN_EMAIL: "mondo+${APP_NAME}@$(APP_EMAIL_DOMAIN)"
      ADMIN_PASSWORD: "${APP_ADMIN_PASSWORD}"
      
      ROBOTS_TXT: "User-agent: *\nDisallow: /"
      
      LOG_LEVEL: "debug"
      LOG_STYLE: "pretty"
      
      TELEMETRY: "false"
      QUERY_LIMIT_MAX: -1

networks:
  cx_directus:
```

```
APP_NAME=cx
APP_KEY=XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
APP_SECRET=XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
APP_ADMIN_PASSWORD=XXXX
APP_EMAIL_DOMAIN=myDomain.com

MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=XXXXXXXXXX
MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=127.0.0.1
MYSQL_HOST=*
MYSQL_DATABASE=cx
MYSQL_USER=directus
MYSQL_PASSWORD=XXXXXXX
```

When I run `docker-compose up` the `redis` and `mysql` containers build fine. Directus however fails when trying to connect to mysql.

I have tried various values for `ports` and `MYSQL_HOST` / `MYSQL_ROOT_HOST`:

- `*`
- `%`
- `localhost`
- `0.0.0.0`
- `127.0.0.1`

And none work. I continue to get the same error:

```bash
cx_directus  | node:internal/process/promises:288
cx_directus  |             triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
cx_directus  |             ^
cx_directus  | 
cx_directus  | Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
cx_directus  |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1555:16)
cx_directus  |     --------------------
cx_directus  |     at Protocol._enqueue (/directus/node_modules/.pnpm/mysql@2.18.1/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
cx_directus  |     at Protocol.handshake (/directus/node_modules/.pnpm/mysql@2.18.1/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
cx_directus  |     at Connection.connect (/directus/node_modules/.pnpm/mysql@2.18.1/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
cx_directus  |     at /directus/node_modules/.pnpm/knex@2.4.2_mysql@2.18.1_pg@8.11.0_sqlite3@5.1.6_tedious@16.1.0/node_modules/knex/lib/dialects/mysql/index.js:66:18
cx_directus  |     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
cx_directus  |     at Client_MySQL.acquireRawConnection (/directus/node_modules/.pnpm/knex@2.4.2_mysql@2.18.1_pg@8.11.0_sqlite3@5.1.6_tedious@16.1.0/node_modules/knex/lib/dialects/mysql/index.js:61:12)
cx_directus  |     at create (/directus/node_modules/.pnpm/knex@2.4.2_mysql@2.18.1_pg@8.11.0_sqlite3@5.1.6_tedious@16.1.0/node_modules/knex/lib/client.js:254:39) {
cx_directus  |   errno: -111,
cx_directus  |   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
cx_directus  |   syscall: 'connect',
cx_directus  |   address: '127.0.0.1',
cx_directus  |   port: 3306,
cx_directus  |   fatal: true
cx_directus  | }
cx_directus  | 
cx_directus  | Node.js v18.18.2
cx_directus exited with code 1
```

I have verified that the `mysql` container IS working, and I am indeed able to login with the `directus user`:

```bash
> docker exec -it cx_mysql bash
bash-4.4# mysql -u directus -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 8
Server version: 8.2.0 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2023, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

What is the next step to get this troubleshot/working?
I'm sure its going to end up being something stupid. ‍♀️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly after more permutations, and even some help from ChatGPT, was unable to solve. I started a brand new instance, and this time it worked. The majority of it is the same, but used mysql `latest` instead of `8.2`, which you'd think is the same... but it worked.

I also used `cx_mysql` as the host, leveraging the internal dns (as @tuneLinux points out)... but before this change as well. Maybe the combination is the fix? ‍♀️

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that individual containers when brought up by docker compose behave as though they are on separate computers. That is they each have an individual IP address on your cx_directus network.

If you run docker network inspect cx_directus you should see this.

Happily, though, docker compose creates an internal DNS resolver for your custom bridge network - cx_directus. So if you use cx_mysql as the database host name within your directus service it should work.

Cheers

Comment: sadly, that was a combination I tried later, and still no result. Ultimately I ended up going to ChatGPT and having it debug  , and it made progress, but in the end I started fresh again and got it to work.